# Event with locked / hidden wall? how? deprecated? hidden parameter?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating an event but i dont want the guests to be able to post on it's wall
 or at least it won't be visible.

Couldn't find the parameter doing so, but i recall events that it was possible (couldn't post on the wall).

I also saw this: [Get permissions for a Facebook Event's Wall](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5503278/get-permissions-for-a-facebook-events-wall)

(no answer)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's an option in the event creation flow, either through the API or the native interface, the only privacy options for events are
 'OPEN' (default), 'CLOSED', or 'SECRET'

(see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#events )

Comment: Yes... i'm aware of that, that's why i've asked. The privacy IS different (as mentioned in that link i've posted)...
Any other ideas maybe? 
I don't want people to be able to see the wall / post on it

Comment: I don't think there's any such option (at least not in the API)